# Got a static var which is working, now  need to get dynamic var which isn't working

Tags: jquery

I've got this variable:

```
 var zvmlist = { 
   'Huishoudelijke hulp': 'Huishoudelijke hulp', 
   'Verpleging thuis': 'Verpleging thuis',
   'Verzorging thuis': 'Verzorging thuis',
   '24 uurs zorg': '24 uurs zorg',
   'Ondersteunende begeleiding': 'Ondersteunende begeleiding',
 };
```

this `var` is used in a function to create a drop-down list:

```
    $.each(zvmlist, function(key, value) { 
  var selected='';
  if(key==eventdata.title){var selected='selected' }
  $('<option value="'+key+'" '+selected+'>'+value+'</option>').appendTo($('#calendar_edit_entry_form_title')); 
  });
```

which works like a charm.

Now I created a function to fetch the list from a MySQL table:

```
 $.get('get_zorgvormen.php', function(data) {

    var zvmlist = '{'+data+'}';
    //alert(zvmlist);

  });
```

When I enable the alert function, it shows me the `var(array)`.

But I it won't act as a variable.

How can I pass this data to my `.each` function?

(You can see it in action here: http://www.zorgzuster-zeeland.nl/site/static/calendar_test.php.)

---

```
 $.each(zvmlist, function(key, value) { 
        var selected='';
        if(key==eventdata.title){var selected='selected' }
        $('<option value="'+key+'" '+selected+'>'+value+'</option>').appendTo($('#calendar_edit_entry_form_title')); 
        });
```

when the var zvmlist= currently

```
var zvmlist = { 
      'Huishoudelijke hulp': 'Huishoudelijke hulp', 
      'Verpleging thuis': 'Verpleging thuis',
      'Verzorging thuis': 'Verzorging thuis',
      '24 uurs zorg': '24 uurs zorg',
      'Ondersteunende begeleiding': 'Ondersteunende begeleiding',
    };
```

but i want to get it populated by:

```
$.get('get_zorgvormen.php', function(data) {
      //data = {"key":"value"};
      var obj = {};
      obj[0] = data;
      var zvmlist = '{'+obj[0]+'}';
      alert(zvmlist);
    });
```

When i delete the static var  the app breaks and wont populate the dropdown

---

I combined both functions, it is kind of working except, the dropdownlist is populated with each letter from the var.

like

```
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">'</option>
<option value="3"> </option>
<option value="4">:</option>
<option value="5"> </option>
<option value="6">'</option>
<option value="7">H</option>
<option value="8">u</option>
```

and so on

```
$.get('get_zorgvormen.php', function(data) {
      //data = {"key":"value"};
      var obj = {};
      obj[0] = data;
      var zvmlist = obj[0];  
     $.each(zvmlist, function(key, value) { 
        var selected='';
        if(key==eventdata.title){var selected='selected' }
        $('<option value="'+key+'" '+selected+'>'+value+'</option>').appendTo($('#calendar_edit_entry_form_title')); 
        });
     });
```

any help will be appriciated

Comment: Its a small tip for in the future, but If you use Firebug, use console.log(variable) instead of alert(variable). You can check in the Firebug console detailed what your variable its type is or its value. Also which methods you can use on it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
var zvmlist = '{'+data+'}';
```

Try

```
var zvmlist = Eval('{' + data + '}');
```

Comment: I removed the static var and added 
$.get('get_zorgvormen.php', function(data) {
   
    var zvmlist = Eval('{' + data + '}');

    //alert(zvmlist);
    
  });

But still not working

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to evaluate that string so it becomes useful. Try:

```
var zvmlist = eval('{'+data+'}');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse JSON data using the eval() function.

```
$.get('get_zorgvormen.php', function(data) { 
   return eval('({' + data + '})');
});
```

Comment: How do pass this to the .each function then?

Answer (score 0):

Without using eval, you could create an object literal first, then pass that to zvmlist.

```
  $.get('get_zorgvormen.php', function(data) {
      //data = {"key":"value"};
      var obj = {};
      obj[0] = data;
      var zvmlist = obj[0];
      alert(zvmlist);
  });
```

not tested, but something like this.

Comment: it doesnt pass the var zvmlist to the .each function

Comment: how does the return from the .get look? is it a json object?